# Search tree like structure HTML table with JavaScript, JQuery. Search results should keep parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, filtering, html-table

I have a table with a tree-structure like this:

```js
$("#treetable").treetable({expandable: true}).treetable("expandAll");
var log = $(".log");

var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name', { data: ['tt-id'] } ]
};

var hackerList = new List('users', options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-alpha1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treetable/3.2.0/css/jquery.treetable.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treetable/3.2.0/css/jquery.treetable.theme.default.min.css">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="users">
  <table id="treetable">
    <thead>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="name">Gender</th>
        </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr data-tt-id='1'>
        <td class="name">tomhanks</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='1.1' data-tt-parent-id='1'>
        <td class="name">timrobbins</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='1.1.1' data-tt-parent-id='1.1'>
        <td class="name">samuel l jackson</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='2'>
        <td class="name">leonardo dicaprio</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='2.1' data-tt-parent-id='2'>
        <td class="name">julia roberts</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='2.1.1' data-tt-parent-id='2.1'>
        <td class="name">arnold schwarzenegger</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='3'>
        <td class="name">jim carrey</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='3.1' data-tt-parent-id='3'>
        <td class="name">dan akroyd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tt-id='3.1.1' data-tt-parent-id='3.1'>
        <td class="name">will smith</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">colin farrell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
    <p class="log"></p>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treetable/3.2.0/jquery.treetable.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.2.0/list.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to filter the table in a way that only the most inner children rows are searchable (in this case: `samuel l jackson`, `arnold schwarzenegger`, `will smith`), and the results should keep their parent rows as well.

I mean if someone is entering the string `"samue"` it should return this:

```
v tomhanks
  v timrobbins
      samuel l jackson
```

Currently I'm using list.js, but I am not insisting on using it. I am sure it is possible with vanillajs or jquery.

Comment: the parent of <td class="name">samuel l jackson</td> is <tr data-tt-id='1.1.1' data-tt-parent-id='1.1'>. All the other rows are the preceding or following siblings. Just to clarify the terminology here.

Comment: After regarding this, it would be helpful if you specify more precisely what should be the result.

Comment: You are right. I meant all the rows above the matched result until it reaches the root.

Comment: I want to keep the hierarchy of the matched result. So not only the sole row gets returned, but their "visual parents" as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I got you better now. So you have a tree-like data structure, which is rendered into a table. Now you are trying to read tree-like data from the table. This will be possible, of course (since you are supplying references to the tree structure via some id tags). Much more convenient would be to search the initial tree-like structure directly and regard the rendering as a separate thing. So: Do you have the initial tree somehow?  E.G as a JSON or nested JavaScript object?

Comment: in other words: how does the data get into your table?

Comment: The data is coming from a JavaScript object and it is rendered to the table via the HandlebarsJS templating engine, that results in a simple HTML table. 
Then comes the JQuery Treetable plugin that defines the hierarchy of the rows. 
I could simply collect the results in an object and reload the page with rendering only the matched elements, but it would be much more elegant to filter the whole thing client-side without reloading the page.

Comment: Alright, so it's rendered on the server side. You could pass the data structure to the client and let the client do with it whatever.. render the whole thing, search for things, re-render... This makes much more sense. Or maybe you already render at the client side, then it's even simpler since the data is already there.  If you want, post the whole file somewhere.

Comment: No, it is rendered on the client-side (the templating and the tree rendering part).

Comment: and how does your initial data-structure look like?

Comment: I can't look it up at the moment, but it is a deeply nested JavaScript object, that is handed to the templating engine on the client side.